# confusion_matrix ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous-multioutput and binary targets

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

after I did CNN training, then do the inference work, when I TRY TO GET classification_report

```
    from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix


    y_proba = trained_model.predict(X_test)
    #y_pred = trained_model.predict(X_test)
    y_pred = np.argmax(trained_model.predict(X_test),axis=1)

    print('Confusion Matrix')
    print(confusion_matrix(y_pred, y_test))
    print('Classification Report')
    print(classification_report(y_pred, y_test))
    print (trained_model.trainable_variables) #Trained Parameters
```

I get this ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous-multioutput and binary targets